# When querying a SQL Server using Invoke-Sqlcmd, the first attempt fails, and subsequent attempts fail as well until some time has passed. Why?

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am invoking a `Sqlcmd` to query a SQL Server in Azure. The first several requests fail, and then after waiting about 30 seconds the same command will work.

Is this an issue with the database needing to spin up before being able to accept queries?

Comment: Are you using Serverless? You can configure `auto-pause delay`

Comment: Is this an Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, or an instance of SQL Server running on an Azure VM?